# Отображение ImageView на экране

Tags: java, android

Здравствуйте! Возникла следующая проблема:
 Есть некий imageview размером 370X2400 png и есть 2 андроид-устройства с диагоналями экранов 4,5 и 5 дюймов. Если запускаю перовое устройство с экраном 4,5 то картинка отображается, хотя и с некоторыми отступами сверху и снизу экрана, а саму картинку можно прокручивать. Идем дальше. Если я запускаю второе устройство с экраном 5 дюймов, то возникает проблема, а именно, сама картинка не отображается, но сам экран прокручивать все также можно. Собственно вопрос заключается в том, с чем может быть связано не отображение ImageView на втором устройстве и есть ли способ избавиться от тех отступов сверху и снизу картинки после запуска первого устройства 
XML-код:

```
<ScrollView 
android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent">
<RelativeLayout 
android:layout_width="match_parent" 
android:layout_height="wrap_content"> 
<LinearLayout
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:gravity="center">
<ImageView
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"  
android:id="@+id/foto_test1"
android:src="@mipmap/foto"
  android:scaleType="centerCrop"/>
</LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Java -Код:

```
public class File_test_1 extends Activity{ 
@Override 
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) { super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); 
setContentView(R.layout.file_test_1); 
ImageView f_test1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.foto_test1); f_test1.setImageResource(R.mipmap.test_1); }}
```

сама картинка test_1.png (mdpi)

Comment: Будьте добры показать код, чтобы предметно разобраться в вашем вопросе.

Comment: + скажите какие версии андроида на одном и другом телефоне.

Comment: Java -Код:public class File_test_1 extends Activity{
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.file_test_1);
        ImageView f_test1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.foto_test1);
        f_test1.setImageResource(R.mipmap.test_1); }}

Comment: XML-код:<ScrollView 
android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent">
<RelativeLayout android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"> <LinearLayout
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:gravity="center"><ImageView
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"  android:id="@+id/foto_test1"android:src="@mipmap/foto"
  android:scaleType="centerCrop"/></LinearLayout></RelativeLayout></ScrollView>

Comment: @user212681, пишите код не в комментарии, а в вопрос, через его правку.

Answer (score 1):

1. Картинка может не отображаться из-за её большого размера. Попробуйте сжать её.
2. За расположение картинки отвечает атрибут `scaleType` у `ImageView`. Попробуйте вот это значение `CENTER_CROP` - так не будет пустых мест на экране, но будет обрезание, если картинка не поместиться на экран.

Comment: Сжать в длину или ширину?

Comment: @user212681 сжать в целом

Comment: @user212681, сжать по обоим измерениям, пропорционально, чтобы не исказилось. Т.е., например, 370х2400 превратить в 37x240.

Comment: Попробовал использовать  значение CENTER_CROP на экране 4,5 отступы пропали, но и края(боковые) картинки были срезаны, а на 5 дюймовом экране картинка все также не отобразилась. Не совсем понял на счет смысла сжатия, ведь картинка 370х2400 все же отображается на устройстве с меньшей диагональю, хотя и с отступами.

Comment: @user212681, чтоб не обрезалась можно попробовать поставить размеры `ImageView` в `wrap_content` или программно установить конкретные значения в пикселях, получив соотношения сторон картинки. Чтобы прокручивать картинку большую - оберните её в ScrollView или используйте к-л либу для этого. Разные девайсы могут иметь разные ограничения на память и уменьшение размеров картинки может помочь, снизив потребление памяти.